# Getting has no method error AngularJS Bootstrap HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Im getting a has no method error when calling this method $scope.getImageReturn();

```
    JS CODE
function imageModalController($scope, $http, employeeFactory, $modalInstance) {

$scope.session = {};
$scope.getImageReturn();
$scope.cancel = function() {

    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};

$scope.signUp = function() {
    // alert("call signUp");
    window.location = "index.html#/signUp";
};

$scope.getImage = function(email) {

    employeeFactory.getImage(mail);

};
$scope.getImageReturn = function() {
    $scope.session.img_source = "test";
        //data.path;
};
```

}

HTML CODE

```
    <div class="modal-body">
<div class="panel panel-info">

    <div class="panel-heading">Attachment</div>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <label>{{img_source}}</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

The modal will popup when getImageReturn is not called. So i know for a fact its just with that function then. Not sure why its happening though and really cant think of a reason of why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this declaration to the top of controller, before you call the method.

```
$scope.getImageReturn = function() {
    $scope.session.img_source = "test";
        //data.path;
};
```

Comment: ty. My problems are always so basic, the complicated ones i can figure out with ease, the "basic" ones take me a bit

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `{{img_source}}` by `{{session.img_source}}` since `img_source` is not attached directly to `$scope`.

Indeed, brackets for data-binding allow you to omit `$scope`, but not intermediary object between `$scope` and your target.

Comment: that doesnt help the problem, however it does help a potential future problem so thank you

Comment: I just used his and it worked the way i wanted it to, the session thing was from a previous code i was using and dont want to use it anymore I appreciate both answers. Ty